# Sharing password between applications

Tags: c#

I have written a application in C# that requires the user to login.

The application contains three sub applications and if the user has identified himself in one applicationn they should not have to login to the others.

The user can start the sub applications from the main application or seperately. Currently im solving it by passing the username and password from the main applications a command line arguments, but i beleive there must be a better way to share the information between applications.

Each application is a seperate assembly. Anyone?

Comment: how do you validate the password?

Comment: where did you store those password and how do you verify it? DB or config file?

Comment: The password are stored in an encrypted xml file and verified by a shared service

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have some sort either shared authentication API between applications or an authentication service that is independent of the applications and all applications. You have not written about how you are implementing the login process - so its hard to give some concrete advice

Comment: Thanks for you answer, basically this is what im already doing , i would although like some share setting that the the other applications could use like Properties.Settings, but the other applications cant read the main applications setting , i think

Comment: In this case I'd probably do something like shared settings provider - like it is described in this article :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136152/Create-a-Custom-Settings-Provider-to-Share-Setting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but i would save it to an (encrypted) file which is checked by startup for every application

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this stuff, but I think there is a simple answer for this - make a flag, that is used by all of the apps. The difference would be that you pass a flag instead of login/username.
If login is successful, flag is true and other applications can start without logging in. Flag turns false as soon as user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming you will only need to authenticate 1 time in each sub application i.e. you dont authenticate each time a user chooses a different functionality within the subapp.

```
1. Main App Loaded
1a. Main App Authenticated
1b. Set db.userSessionExpiry = DateAdd(Now + 10 minutes) (for the user inquestion)
2a. User opens the sub app 
(you pass the username to subapp) or (sub app gets the winlogin user) or other
2b. Sub app checks for the session expiry for this user
2c. If the expiry time (from 1b) has gone past now, re-authenticate. 
2d. Set db.userSessionExpiry = DateAdd(Now + 10 minutes) (for the user inquestion)
```

this way you wont be passing passwords around and will leave the authentication to the user.

imagine if your user has started the main app and left (his screen unlocked), you have left an open authenticated toke for the rest of the users to access and work on the sub apps

you can configure the session timeout other than 10 minutes (for e.g. 20 minutes as default websession timeout)

Now if you need to authenicate users at a function level (as against at startup), then you will need to call 1b above everytime a function is executed.

I hope that makes sense and it helps